# Obtaining a list of arrays by diagonally traversing a 2D array with left-leaning diagonal sections?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration

I know I can just use `for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)` or a enhanced for-loop to iterate completely through a loop.

However, I am trying to create new char[] arrays by completely iterating diagonally through a rectangular 2D array, while taking left-leaning sections (instead of your usual right-leaning sections).

*In other words*, look at the image below. I'd like each char[] array to be made up of all the chars between two of the red diagonal lines in the image below.

[image]

So, if the iteration starts in the top-right corner, the first array made would be, `['q']`, the second would be `['e', 'w']`, the third, `['d', 'j', 'e']` etc.

**Here is the diagram code:**

```
private static char[][] bigArray = {
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'q'},
        {'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'w'},
        {'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'e'},
        {'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'r'},
        {'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z', 't'}};
```

Trying to iterate left-leaning diagonals makes it difficult to always know the length of the array I am using. Especially since the new char[] arrays I create will be of different lengths.

*Is there a way I can tell java to stop iterating at a particular length for each array I create?*

Comment: can you add some code or maybe a diagram? I'm not sure I understand the problem here, especially that _left/right-leaning section_?

Comment: @molamk I have added the diagram. Please let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Can you add the code which is in the diagram?

Comment: @driftking9987 I've added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Trying to iterate left-leaning diagonals makes it difficult to always know the length of the array I am using. Especially since the new char[] arrays I create will be of different lengths.

To **calculate the diagonal's length** (the size of your new `char[]`) based on your current position in the matrix `bigArray` (with indices `i` and `j`) do this

```
int newCharArrayLength = Math.min(height - i, width - j);
```

## Implementation (explanation below)

```
private static List<char[]> getDiagonalsList(char[][] arr) {
    List<char[]> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    int height = arr.length;
    int width = arr[0].length;
    int numberOfDiagonals = arr.length + arr[0].length - 1;

    for (int diagonalIdx = 0; diagonalIdx < numberOfDiagonals; diagonalIdx++) {
        int i = Math.max(diagonalIdx - width + 1, 0);
        int j = Math.max(width - diagonalIdx - 1, 0);
        int currentDiagonalLength = Math.min(height - i, width - j);
        int idx = 0;

        char[] charArr = new char[currentDiagonalLength];
        while (i < height && j < width)
            charArr[idx++] = arr[i++][j++];

        ans.add(charArr);
    }

    return ans;
}
```

## A `main` function

You can write a `main` function like this to output your result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] arr = {
            {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'q'},
            {'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'w'},
            {'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'e'},
            {'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'r'},
            {'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'z', 't'}};

    for (char[] diag : diagonal(arr))
        System.out.println(diag);
}
```

## Output

The result will look like this

```
q
ew
dje
cior
bhntt
agmsz
flrx
kqw
pv
u
```

## Explanation and Algorithm

1. Initialize a `List` of `char[]`. This is where you'll put your diagonals at each iteration
2. Calculate the total `numberOfDiagonals` for your rectangle. You can do this by **summing the width and height** minus one (repeated corner)
3. Calculate your `i` index. This can be done by **substracting your rectangle's width from the diagonal index** minus one (because we start indexing at 0). This index should always be positive
4. Calculate your `j` index. Same principle as before but you reverse your subtraction since we want a reverse diagonal. This also needs to be positive
5. Calculate your `currentDiagonalLength`. To do this which is **smaller**, the **distance between *current row `(i)`* and height OR *current column `(j)`* and width**
6. Initialize an array that will hold your diagonal with the previously computed length
7. Add the items one by one. At each iteration increment your *current row `i`* and *current column `j`*
8. Append that array to the list mentioned in **step 1**
9. Repeat **step 3** to **step 8** until you do all diagonals